# Getting a summary of a model in pytorch for an autoencoder

Tags: pytorch

I have the following code:

```py
device = 'mps' if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else 'cpu'
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dims):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(784, 512)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(512, latent_dims)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        return self.linear2(x)

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dims):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(latent_dims, 512)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(512, 784)

    def forward(self, z):
        z = F.relu(self.linear1(z))
        z = torch.sigmoid(self.linear2(z))
        return z.reshape((-1, 1, 28, 28))

class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dims):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(latent_dims)
        self.decoder = Decoder(latent_dims)

    def forward(self, x):
        z = self.encoder(x)
        return self.decoder(z)

def train(autoencoder, data, epochs=20):
    opt = torch.optim.Adam(autoencoder.parameters())
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for x, y in data:
            x = x.to(device) # GPU
            opt.zero_grad()
            x_hat = autoencoder(x)
            loss = ((x - x_hat)**2).sum()
            loss.backward()
            opt.step()
    return autoencoder

latent_dims = 2
autoencoder = Autoencoder(latent_dims).to(device) # GPU

data = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        torchvision.datasets.MNIST('./data',
               transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
               download=True),
        batch_size=128,
        shuffle=True)

autoencoder = train(autoencoder, data)
```

Now I would like to get the summary of the model. In keras I would typically call something like `mymodel.summary()`.

However in pytorch I am using the torchsummary package:

```
import torchsummary
torchsummary.summary(autoencoder, input_size = (28,28))
```

However I get an error:

`RuntimeError: Placeholder storage has not been allocated on MPS device!`?

I realize I moved the model to MPS but why still the error?

Also, where does the model convert the 28x28 - >784 in the encoding layer? Is it smart enough to reshape automatically?

Comment: The package you're using hasn't been updated since pytorch 1.5. It's likely out of date for your pytorch version.

Comment: @Karl do you have another suggestion?